# Стоит ли мобильным разработчикам опасаться веб-разработчиков

Tags: mobile, веб-программирование

Сейчас не секрет, что в мобильной сфере набирают обороты фрэймворки на Html5+js, в частности есть платформы где эти фрэймворки используются официально (Blackberry, WebOS, windows 8) а в других реализована отличная поддержка (PhoneGap). Ну и + сам мобильный веб.

Заказчики хотят чтобы приложение работало на многих платформах, поэтому им выгоднее, чтобы оно делалось именно вышеуказанным методом. Это значит, что рынок будет расти, и обычные веб-разрабы/верстальщики, почуяв это, будут постепенно захватывать данную сферу, смещая разработчиков java/c#/obj-c. Что думает публика по этому поводу?

Comment: Прямо как в том анекдоте про Тбилисский ТЮЗ: "Ой, боюсь, боюсь!"

Comment: Я и тех и других боюсь учитывая качество их вторичной продукции...

Comment: С т.з. разработки под моб. устройства - нет, не стоит (это не значит что у JavaScript'а там нет места, есть, но когда используют его решают другого рода задачи), а вот с т.з. десктопа - думаю да, но не "сегодня".

На потяжении, скажем, лет 5и JavaScript может занять лидирующие позиции, но, ИМХО, беспокоиться по этому поводу - рановато

Comment: > Стоит ли мобильным разработчикам опасаться веб-разработчиков

Зависит от того, у кого из них бита есть.

Answer (score 10):

Мне кажется, что можно будет начать об этом думать, когда произойдет следующая совокупность событий:

- Веб-приложения на `HTML5` начнут работать с такой же степенью детерминированности, как и обычные `Java / C# / Objective C` приложения.
- Появится хотя бы один прецедент использования `HTML5` для создания основного клиента, скажем, для какого-нибудь сервиса типа `Facebook` *(насколько я знаю, пока таких нет, хотя, разумеется, могу заблуждаться).* Поделки непромышленного масштаба из разряда *"P2P клиент на `Haskell`"* не в счет.

---

**Update:**

- Строго доказывать здесь что-либо сложно, поскольку сфера `IT` и ее рынок вакансий по своей *непредсказуемости* сравнимы с биржевыми рынками. Естественно, я не обладаю достаточной компетенцией в вопросах их аналитики, но могу попробовать *"отбиться"* следующими тезисами:

> - Кроссплатформенность веб-приложений - это такой же миф, как, например, кроссплатформенность приложений на `Java` или `Qt`. Да, платформа позволяет, но сделать универсальное приложение, которое по своей степени продуманности, использования возможностей конкретной платформы и уровню когнитивного диссонанса у пользователя будет **действительно кроссплатформенным** - это архисложная задача. Естественно, что это же относится к `HTML5`, а значит сама по себе концепция универсальной платформы для приложений начинает терять свой шарм.
> - Про использование аппаратных возможностей девайсов и сложность написания действительно безопасного `sandbox'a` вам уже ответил [@Dex.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/878/dex)
> - Если бы перспективность использования `HTML5` для таких целей была бы неоспоримой, то  ее бы использовали в промышленных масштабах. Но никто этого не делает, потому что бессмысленно откидывать имеющуюся кодовую базу, набор интеграционных `solution'ов`, информацию обо всех сложностях, возникших при разработке и весь накопленный фидбек от пользователей просто ради того, чтобы опробовать новую технологию. *Это же переписывание приложения с нуля!*
> - А те компании, которые только задумываются над созданием мобильных клиентов для своих сервисов, ориентируются на уже имеющиеся решения других компаний и вряд ли будут экспериментировать из-за страха нарваться на негативный фидбек *("Я не понял, что это за фигня, где у вас **обычное** приложение?")* и растерять и без того не слишком большое число пользователей. Может быть, конечно, использование `HTML5` для таких вещей и не за горами, но точно не в ближайшем будущем - для этого нужен существенный `shift` парадигмы.
> - *Почему, как вы думаете, на `Youtube` стандартный плеер - не `HTML5`?*
> - Продолжая разговор про `Youtube` - попробуйте, например, написать им письмо и спросить: *"Как так получилось, что ваш клиент для `Android` не на `HTML5`????!?! Это же так круто и прогрессивно!"* Думаю, что ответ будет схож *(если он вообще будет :)* с ответом тем студентам, которые приходят в `gamedev` и начинают толкать свои идеи про [**переписывание `AI` с помощью нейронных сетей.**](http://lib.custis.ru/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%B2_%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85_(%D0%95%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0_ADD-2010))

---

**Update2:**

**http://habrahabr.ru/post/151337/**

Comment: Всё это конечно хорошо. Да вот только клиентов и соответственно работодателей мало интересует. Имхо потребность в js/html5 разработчиках будет расти (и растёт уже сейчас) а потребность в нативных разработчиках будет соответственно угасать. Разумеется всегда будут оставаться настоящие гуру, но конкуренция среди них будет огроменная. Если считаете, что я неправ докажите обратное. Я даже верю и хочу этого

Comment: Не думаю, что в скором времени будет так прекрасно развит HTML/JS чтобы с адекватным уровнем безопасности получить доступ к возможностям телефона. Не говоря уже о том, сколько всего должно будет поместиться в один JS, чтобы доступ к различным функциям телефона сделать унифицированным. Моделей телефонов, а, соответственно, и их функций настолько огромное количество, что я даже теряюсь в догадках, возможно ли сделать такой "обобщенный" функциональный набор в JS. А если каждый начнет пихать в JS свои функции, то это будет противоречить вашему условию в вопросе.

Comment: @alvin Ответил вам апдейтом.

Comment: @Dex как раз тенденция идёт к унификации. Все крупнейшие ос используют webkit, стоит ли напоминать что появление w8 тоже повлечет возможность поддержки этого движка. Получается что всё упрётся в производительность, но и тут арм и квалкомм не дают заскучать. Всё остальное со временем отомрёт в связи с неконкурентоспособностью. 

Касательно youtube ответ прост: рано. Html5 находится на стадии экспермента, но через год-два он точно станет основным. Не такой яркий, но очень удачный пример переезда на html5 http://www.beatport.com/. Вопрос только во времени

Comment: @alvin

- Вспоминается [**вот что.**][1]

- В `IT` загадывать на два года вперед - это непозволительная роскошь. Тот же *Торвальдс* пришел с `Git'ом` и за полгода нанес сильнейший фланговый удар по `Subversion,` оттяпав себе нехилый кусок сегмента. Откуда вы знаете, что с мобильными девайсами не произойдет какой-нибудь похожей истории?

[1]: http://blog.dioxid.ru/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/RTS-2008.jpg

Comment: Как это на youtube нет HTML5?!! А это тогда что: http://www.youtube.com/html5 ? У меня даже сами ютубовцы его стандартным сделали, хотя я их об этом не просил.

Comment: @alvin, мне вот интересно, какой список функций нужно реализовать и сколько аппаратов нужно перепробовать, чтобы в WebKit добавить поддержку, например, работу с камерой? А как в HTML5 будет реализована многопоточность, сервисы и демоны? Например, жизненный цикл Андроид приложений не дает возможности только в одном браузере делать сразу несколько вещей. Тут в принципе не может быть унификации, перечисление одних только вендоров займет уйму времени.

Comment: @Dobby007 Я где-то писал, что в `Youtube` **нет** `HTML5`? Его включают выборочно, примерно так же как когда-то включали новый интерфейс `Google`. Там четко написано, что `HTML5` плеер находится в режиме тестирования. О его стабильности уже [ходят легенды.][1]
[1]: https://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&newwindow=1&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=youtube+html5+%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82&fp=56d97fd720959475

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, да... че-то я проглядел видимо. Думал, что вы написали, что его вообще нет. А плеер html5 у меня тормозил, причем тормозил жестко. Я сначала не понимал почему на ютубе видео стало тормозить, думал, что из-за превьюшек на прогресс баре. Но как только щелкнул правой мышкой по плееру, так сразу понял. Ну и естественно так же быстро его переключил на flash'овский))

Comment: @Dex я не отрицаю что html5 сейчас имеет множество недостатков, связанных с камерой и прочим железом. Но такие возможности используют только отсилы 5% всех приложений (я щас не говорю об играх). Остальные же 95% пользуют только базовый функционал: веб/интерфейс/кэш (включая клиенты ВК/twitter/facebook). Многопоточность - это риальне проблема. И это действительно важный плюс в пользу нативных языков. Я даже не знаю чем там может похвастаться js) таймеры разве что? А жизненный цикл больше важен самой ОС чем приложению и при необходимости это можно допилить и самому

Comment: @alvin, вы пытаетесь получить ответ на свой вопрос или все же доказать, что HTML5 - всему голова?

Жизненный цикл вы вряд ли допилите, как только одна активити перекрывает другую - первая замирает. В любом случае без нативных, ничего не получится. Перечитайте все, что написал @Котик\_хочет\_кушать, вам станет, может, немного понятнее почему. В конце-концов, пока не будет стабильности веб, которой пока не хватает, меня такие приложения будут не на шутку бесить и пользоваться ими лично я не буду, ведь есть замена лучше.

Comment: > Я даже не знаю чем там может похвастаться js) таймеры разве что?

Чем таймеры в JavaScript превосходят таймеры, например, в Qt?

Comment: @Dex в вопросе я задал вопрос, что думает публика по этому поводу, а не "скажите как мне быть", то есть подразумевал возможность дискуссии на эту тему. По поводу Lifecycle повторю: это важно самой ос для управления ресурсами. Вы можете сами внутри js добавить нужные вам ивенты и очищать данные по мере необходимости. "бесить и пользоваться ими лично я не буду" а вы заказчик чтоли? клиентов ещё раз повторю не интересует отношение программистов к этому вопросу. Им нужно кроссплатформенно/качественно/недорого. Не можете качественно - мы найдём других

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос конечно интересный... Мне кажется опасаться стоит ровно в той же мере насколько стоит опасаться десктопным приложениям "наступления" веб подобных приложений.

Ну например насколько стоит опасаться разработчикам игр вроде [Call Of Duty](http://www.callofduty.com/) наступления [flash игр](http://girsa.ru/)? Смешно?

В общем, я думаю, что в ближайшие 5-6 лет опасаться ничего не надо.

Comment: @alvin да какая в принципе разница? Суть то не меняется - десктопы намного богаче чем поделушки на html+js

Answer (score 1):

Опасаться очевидного глупо, нужно учиться... Это с одной стороны, а с другой html5+js - тема не менее сложная и интересная, чем java/c#/obj-c, и, чтобы добиться в ней успеха, нужно очень много знать и уметь. К тому же технология html5 будет окончательно оформлена лет через пять, а перспективы java/c#/obj-c пока очень сложно ограничивать сроком пять или даже десять лет.

Comment: ну оформлены будут стандарты, а применяется то технология уже сейчас. И мне например эта технология не интересна (не спрашивайте почему). Вопрос стоит ли изучать это несмотря на свои воззрения или всё-таки в определённый момент настанет такая необходимость когда обычные языки станут не нужны